# GDB Not Displaying File Paths when Setting Breakpoints

Tags: debugging, gdb

Hello Stack Overflow community!

So I am currently in the middle of taking a course on Operating Systems and I am trying to use the GDB debugger to set breakpoints to trace execution of some code for OS 161. I've played around with it for a few hours, but Im having a hard time understanding why the debugger just displays the function name instead of the file path to where the function is. For example, the code to display the menu is located in **/os161/os161-1.11/kern/main/main.c** and there is a function (threadtest3) that is called while when an option called "tt3" is selected by the user and it is located in a file called tt3.c. Its path is: **~/os161/os161-1.11/kern/test/tt3.c**

The issue I'm having is not setting breakpoints, the issue I'm trying to figure out is why gdb only displays the function namewhen it is called and not the full path. For example, When I set a breakpoint at the start of the function threadtest3, once I select the "tt3" option in the menu, the debugger shows this:

[image]

See how the debugger displays a backtrace, but only the function names that have been called anod nothing about where the files are or what line in one function called another? Im not sure why its like that compared how the debugger prints out the line number of where the execution is in the file start.S, which in this picture is line 163.

I am using GDB version 6.6 (Windows 10 as well if that is relevant information) and at first I thought it was the version of my debugger, but there is a user on Youtube who has the same version and his output doesn't behave like mine is. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4PYFgzevQ0)

Any ideas?

Thanks for any insight you mgiht be able to provide.

*****UPDATE 3/11/2018/ *******

So I tried editing the defs.mk file which according to the comments holds all of the keywaords and constants used to compile. This file is located in this directory shown below [image]When I first looked in this file defs.mk, the flag CC was just set to cs161-gcc. So after some research and looking through similar debugging problems on this site, I tried to update this line by writing CC = cs161-gcc - g3 -ggdb. I also di a similar thing for HOST_CC and HOST_LDCC which you can see here in the picture below.[image] Then after going to the directory /os161/os161-1.11/kern/compile/ASST1, I ran make clean to remove all of the object files created when running make. Then I reconfigured the kernel by going to /os161/os161-1.11/kern/conf and running ./config ASST1. When I get back to /os161/os161-1.11/kern/compile/ASST1 and run make after running make depend, I can see that it shows the changes being make and it looks like it is compiling the files with debug mode turned on, but I still have to same issue. You can see the output of running make below  [image]

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas?

Your code was not compiled for debugging. You need to rebuild it with `-g` flag.

The `start.S` (which you link from `libc`) *was* compiled with `-g`, and so it shows file and line number.

> So would I place the -g flag near ./config ASST1? Or somewhere else?

You'll need to read `./config` and figure it out.

If your `config` looks like [this](https://github.com/vivekbhalla/OS161/blob/master/src/kern/conf/config), you'll need to edit `ASST1` and make sure that there is `debug` directive in it, like [here](https://github.com/vivekbhalla/OS161/blob/master/src/kern/conf/ASST1#L5).

**Update:**

Your command lines show that `-g` is in fact being used.

Your problem then is likely that you are debugging the wrong binary.

It is common to build a full-debug executable, then run `strip` on a copy of it. The stripped copy is the one you download to your target (or emulator), and is much smaller (because all debug info has been removed from it). The *unstripped* copy is the one you want to give to your debugger. If you give debugger a stripped copy, it will still work, but not in a way you want it to work.

Comment: Ah I see, so when a configure the kernel I have to put the -g flag for that command? The instructions for our current project tell us to configure the kernel like this:                                                           % cd ~/os161/os161-1.11/kern/conf 
 % ./config ASST1                                                                             %cd ~/os161/os161-1.11/kern/compile/ASST1
  % make depend
  % make
  % make install So would I place the -g flag near ./config ASST1? Or somewhere else? (Sorry for the cramped format)

Comment: Ok. I will look through this and keep you posted. Thanks

Comment: So from what I can tell, the config file that I have looks like the one on github and ASST1 indeed does have a debug directive in it. So I'm guessing if thats the case then I shouldn't have to edit ASST1 and should just funnel through ./config until I find how to insert it right? I find it quite odd though, that our professor didn't give us any warning on this and I'd have to go through all of this just to get the debugger to do something useful. I assumed that they would have added -g flags for us since these are files that we didn't write in the first place.

Comment: Updated the post above with photos to show what I have done so far

Comment: @avenger12 Updated answer.